# Receiving planet basemaps in earth-engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, planet

I am working on satellite imagery from the NICFI Program which is available on planet.com I am trying to download those basemaps in earth-engine.

I followed this setup [guide](https://developers.planet.com/docs/integrations/gee/quickstart/) and have connected my gee account with planet.com, but I don't understand how to use their order API ([documentation](https://developers.planet.com/docs/orders/)). I tried a few combinations of item Ids but can't figure out what the item id for a basemap or a quad will be.

Can someone help me out

endpoint -

```
https://api.planet.com/compute/ops/orders/v2
```

body -

```
{
"name":"test order",
"products":[
    {"item_ids":["364-1203"],
    "item_type":"PSScene4Band",
    "product_bundle":"analytic"}
],
"delivery":{
    "google_earth_engine":{
        "project":"planet-webapp",
        "collection":"test_quad"
    }
 }
}
```

response -

```
{
    "field": {
        "Details": [
            {
                "message": "Item ID 364-1203 / Item Type PSScene4Band doesn't exist"
            }
        ]
    },
    "general": [
        {
            "message": "Unable to accept order"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm late to find this. The NICFI Basemaps are actually hosted directly in GEE so there's no need to order them. Here's the instructions for how to get access https://developers.planet.com/docs/integrations/gee/nicfi/

If you have questions on how to use the Orders API for delivery to GEE please feel free to contact Planet support team.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).